# CCAnimate inside of CCSequence creates not CCFiniteTimeAction error

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

this is probably a very quick and easy answer for someone, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out as a noob. I'm trying to run my CCAnimation and then run a second action that removes the animation from the screen upon completion. Before I can get to that point I'm getting a "Incompatible pointer types sending 'CCAction *' to parameter of type 'CCFiniteTimeAction *'" error. I suspect I need to use something besides CCRepeat to run my animation, but I'm not sure what to replace it with. Thank you!!

```
        NSMutableArray *crabAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        [crabAnimFrames addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bashCrab%d.png",i]]];
    }

    CCAnimation *crabAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:crabAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    float randomOffset = CCRANDOM_X_Y(-winSize.height * 0.25, winSize.height * 0.25);
    render.node = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bashCrab1.png"];
    render.node.position = ccp(winSize.width * 0.25, winSize.height * 0.5 + randomOffset);
    render.crabWalk = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:crabAnim] times:1];

    [_batchNode addChild:render.node];

    [render.node runAction:[CCSequence actions:render.crabWalk, nil]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is crabWalk defined? If it is CCAction* change it to CCFiniteTimeAction*.

Comment: YES THANK YOU! My suspicions were correct, I was missing something super obvious in retrospect!

Comment: Steffen: Is this because CCSequence (or CCAction) has changed?